# Объединение текста и текстового столбца

Tags: sql-server

Здравствуйте! В таблице есть записи мужчин и женщин. При выборке таблицы, хочу дописать к колонке, где содержатся фамилии, 'мистер', если пол мужской или 'миссис', если пол женский. Подскажите как сделать, если кто знает конечно.

```
--создание базы
CREATE DATABASE zzz
--выбор базы
USE zzz
GO

--создание таблицы
CREATE TABLE People (
 IDPeople INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1, 1), 
 LastName NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
 FirstName NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
 Sex BIT NOT NULL, -- 1 Мужчина, 0 Женщина
 Age TINYINT NOT NULL
)
--вставляем данные
INSERT INTO People(LastName, FirstName, Sex, Age) VALUES
(N'Иванов', N'Евгений', 1, 18),
(N'Петров', N'Владимир', 1, 22),
(N'Кузьмина', N'Елена', 0, 20),
(N'Сидоров', N'Иван', 1, 19),
(N'Антонова', N'Людмила', 0, 20),
(N'Сумская', N'Виктория', 0, 25)
```

1 вариант, почему-то не правильный

```
DECLARE @sex BIT = (SELECT Sex FROM People)
IF @sex = 1
 SELECT 'Mr. ' + LastName, FirstName, Sex, Age FROM People
ELSE
 SELECT 'Mrs. ' + LastName, FirstName, Sex, Age FROM People
```

2 вариант, почему-то не правильный

```
DECLARE @zero INT = 0
DECLARE @variable INT
SET @variable = (SELECT COUNT(LastName) FROM People)
DECLARE @sex BIT = (SELECT Sex FROM People)

WHILE @variable != 0
BEGIN
 --приращение
 SET @variable -= 1
 --PRINT 'Hello World!'

 IF @sex = 1
  SELECT 'Mr. ' + LastName, FirstName, Sex, Age FROM People
 ELSE
  SELECT 'Mrs. ' + LastName, FirstName, Sex, Age FROM People

 --выход из цикла
 IF(@variable = 0)
 BEGIN
  BREAK
 END
END
```

Comment: Маленький ревью для вас: Для хранения пола человека есть стандарт:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_5218

Comment: Спасибо! Я только изучаю T-SQL и не знал этого. Я думаю, что тип столбца должен выглядеть так наверное `Sex TINYINT NOT NULL DEFAULT = '0'  CHECK(Sex=1 OR Sex=2 OR Sex=0 OR Sex=9)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
(CASE Sex WHEN 1 THEN 'Mr. ' ELSE 'Mrs. ' END) +  LastName,
FirstName, Sex, Age FROM People
```

Comment: Огромное Вам спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Sql Server 2012+

```
select iif(Sex=1, N'Mr.', N'Mrs.'), LastName, FirstName, Sex, Age from People
```